# From the clrs book, why is the insertion sort for loop iterated n times?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

[image]

Why is the first line iterated n times, when it starts at 2? Shouldn't it be n-1 instead? 
Also why is it that line 2 and 3 is n-1 and not n?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the loop statement is considered to be executed one more time, because it's compared both before the first iteration and after the last iteration. Let's consider `A.length = 3`. We have only two iterations, but three comparisons:

```
j := 2
if j > A.length then exit the loop // first comparison, false
... first loop iteration goes

j := j + 1 // j = 3 now
if j > A.length then exit the loop // second comparison, false
... second loop iteration goes

j := j + 1 // j = 4 now
if j > A.length then exit the loop // third comparison, true
```

Thus as you can see we have to compare three times, but the loop body is executed only twice. The first comparison is necessary, because if `A.length = 1` we should not execute the loop body at all.